# draw network in pajek3xl

Tags: social-networking, network-analysis, pajek

I installed [pajek3xl](http://mrvar.fdv.uni-lj.si/pajek/) but just do not seem to be able to simply draw a network given a .net file. There used to be a draw menu but I cannot find it. is it still possible to draw a network in pajek3xl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pajek3XL is meant for analysis of huge networks (over 2 billion of vertices).
For such networks visualization is not needed.
If you need visualization simply use ordinary Pajek,
which is installed when running Install Shield as well.